# Como conectar no SQLAchemy usando arroba (@) na senha do MySql

Tags: mysql, python, flask, sqlalchemy

Para criar uma conexão entre o **Flask** e o **MySql** eu utilizei o **SQLAlchemy** que pede a seguinte string para conectar:

```
mysql://user:password@host/database
```

Eu fiz a seguinte linha:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:iniciosenha@@finalsenha@localhost/mk_rb_manager'
```

Como pode ver, minha senha possui um arroba (@), mas o SQLAlchemy utiliza o arroba (@) para separar `user:password` do `host` e isso conflita na hora de conectar, pois ele entende que o arroba da senha é o arroba que separa o `host` e gera o seguinte erro:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '@finalsenha@localhost' (11003)")
```

Ou seja, ele entende que `@finalsenha@localhost` é o host pata conectar e executa tudo errado.

Tem alguma maneira de utilizar arroba na minha senha do MySql sem que o SQLAlchemy fique com essa confusão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema seria fazendo um `escaping` da string de conexão ao banco de dados. A maneira indicada na documentação é usando o [`urllib`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#mysql).

Na documentação ele dá o seguinte exemplo:

```
import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus("kx%jj5/g")
'kx%25jj5%2Fg'
```

Usando esta estratégia é possível criar a conexão, basta "montar" usando o método [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```py
import urllib.parse

usuario = 'bonzão'
senha = 'iniciosenha@@finalsenha'
urllib.parse.quote_plus(usuario)
# 'bonz%C3%A3o'
urllib.parse.quote_plus(senha)
# 'iniciosenha%40%40finalsenha'
conexao_banco = "mysql://{}:{}@localhost/mk_rb_manager"
print(conexao_banco.format(urllib.parse.quote_plus(usuario),urllib.parse.quote_plus(senha)))
# mysql://bonz%C3%A3o:iniciosenha%40%40finalsenha@localhost/mk_rb_manager
```

Após fazer esses ajustes basta aplicar esta estratégia ao seu caso concreto.

A versão final ficaria:

```py
usuario = 'bonzão'
senha = 'iniciosenha@@finalsenha'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://{}:{}@localhost/mk_rb_manager'.format(urllib.parse.quote_plus(usuario), urllib.parse.quote_plus(senha))
```

Verifique que neste exemplo estou assumindo que as variáveis `usuario` e `senha` já foram declaradas previamente, se não for o caso é possível passar a `string` diretamente como parâmetro.

Por exemplo:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://{}:{}@localhost/mk_rb_manager'.format(urllib.parse.quote_plus('meuusuáriotop'), urllib.parse.quote_plus('senhaforte!@#)(*'))
```

Para saber mais pode consultar a documentação da [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)